# VHDL Altera Qartus random data in unsigned register after (others => 0) + 1

Tags: vhdl, fpga, intel-fpga, quartus

I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting problems with my clock enable timer in a UART controller. The counter is cntR. It should start counting from zero after a condition is met, yet it starts at zero and then switches to a random number instead of incrementing 0 to 1. Here's the process code where something bad happens:

```
process(reset, clock)
begin
    if reset = '1' then
        cntR <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        if rcv_reg = r_idle and rxd = '1' then
            cntR <= (others => '0');
        else
            if cntR = DIVVALUE then
                cntR <= (others => '0');
            else
                cntR <= cntR + 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

here are the declarations (probably not that important):

```
entity SART is
generic(
    INCLK : natural := 50000000;
    BAUDRATE : natural := 9600;
    CNT_WIDTH : natural := 14
);
port(
    clock : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    send : in std_logic;
    rxd : in std_logic;
    data_in : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    data_ready : out std_logic;
    clear_to_send : out std_logic;
    txd : out std_logic;
    data_out : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
end SART;

-- Receiver FSM states
type RCV_STATE_TYPE is (
    r_idle,
    r_start,
    r_data1,r_data2,r_data3,r_data4,r_data5,r_data6,r_data7,r_data8,
    r_stop1
);
signal rcv_reg, rcv_next : RCV_STATE_TYPE;
signal cntR : unsigned(CNT_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
```

This is what I get from Signal Tap:

[image]

For the record, I'm using Altera Quartus 13.0.0 and a DE0-Nano with a Cyclone IV FPGA.

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: Your signal tap waveform shows neither the signals causing a reset nor the clock. I was curious about the reset. See [SART – transmisja szeregowa z wykorzystaniem RS ...](http://rawski.zpt.tele.pw.edu.pl/pl/system/files/Projekt_simpleUART(kolor).pdf) and [kod vhdl](http://burza.hapay.pl/code/uart.vhd) have as elaborate reset conditions. I take it cntR is used to center baud sample rxd.  You appear to have a problem associated with clock speed and setup or hold time. The DIVVALUE declaration isn't visible, can cntR width be reduced? Your clock is 50 Mhz as opposed to 25.

Comment: This is a hardware debugging and not a specific software question. Consider asking it on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As you probably figured out I was using the presentation in your first link to write a UART controller. I get an idle state and a zero counter after a reset.

Comment: Here is a Signal Tap screenshot http://imgur.com/a/rQFHH. Actually the problem I described above only happens every once in a while when I try to subsequently receive a couple hundred bytes. The whole source file is here: https://gist.github.com/jstefanowicz/22239f86990706dfa948737f25316705 The cntR width can be one bit shorter as I'm using a 50 MHz clock. You are probably right about the source of the problem. The Time Quest analyzer says that I can have a max clock speed of about 100 MHz, but I didn't constrain any paths, not even the clock. Do you think that this may be the solution?

Comment: The Mariusz Rawski slide set appears to be about about how to deal with timing issues. Include all his changes (you have r_stop2 commented out in the type declaration but still in the case statement in your github link).  Try using an additional stop bit on the transmit  end to get a cntR set to zero when in r_idle. What can stop cntR from being cleared during r_idle?  Your 'every once in while' in 'a couple hundred bytes' could be `cntR = PULSVALUE` drift without the r_idle set to all zeros. The rest can be setup or hold (skew) on your data_in/out or flow controls. Think FIFO or latches.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input :). I have included all the changes from the slides. I'm using two stop bits on the PC side and If you look closely, the r_stop2 state in the case statement is also commented out. If you take a look at the first signal tap screenshot you can see that the random data apears in the register only after adding 1 to cntR, before that the register contains zeros only. As for setup/hold violations it's possible that they are caused by clock skew, right? I'll constrain the clock signal and see if that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118128/discussion-between-jurek-stefanowicz-and-user1155120).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this problem. It turns out, that I didn't have an SDC file in the project and hence the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer report stated that my maximum clock frequency is 10 times higher that when I had the SDC file attached. After writing an SDC file containing only clock declarations I got a maximum clock frequency of about 7 MHz from TimeQuest. I generated a PLL to get a 5 MHz frequency clock and now everything works flawlessly.